# Display Current Video in Windows Phone 8 using AudioVideoCaptureDevice?

Tags: c#, video, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, video-capture

I've managed to setup code for a Windows Phone 8 Application that initializes and can start/stop recording video using an AudioVideoCaptureDevice. (saves it to an IRandomAccessStream)

```
//Initialize Camera Recording
Windows.Foundation.Size resolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(640, 480);
captureDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, resolution);
captureDevice.VideoEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureVideoFormat.H264;
captureDevice.AudioEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureAudioFormat.Aac;
captureDevice.RecordingFailed += captureDevice_RecordingFailed;
```

However, I cannot figure out how to hook this recording up to a VideoBrush to display the recording to the user.  I want the user to be able to see the video they are recording as it is happening...

I know there is a tutorial that shows how to do this using the old APIs for Windows Phone 7 (CaptureSource, VideoDevice, etc.) but I specifically need to use the AudioVideoCaptureDevice to record.  Anyone know how to display this video on screen?

Comment: do you know how to take a thumbnail of this video? Also I am facing problem using front camera. Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898769/how-to-record-video-using-audiovideocpturedevice-in-wp8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve my problem.

Apparently there is a library in Microsoft.Devices that contains extensions for the VideoBrush class.
Therefore, in order to set the videobrush source to an AudioVideoCaptureDevice, you must first have:

```
using Microsoft.Devices;
```

at the top of your class in which your using the videobrush.
Hope this is able to help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply use [`VideoBrush.SetSource(captureDevice)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee653015%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: VideoBrush doesn't allow you to use an AudioVideoCaptureDevice, only a CaptureSource.

Comment: With the extension (in Microsoft.Devices as mentioned above) this works fine.